# change the way mysql returns columns to php zf 2 sql

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

Im getting using Zend\Db\Sql.

The two tables often share similar columns names, {id,name,...}

When I access the result set, the column names are often overwritten because of this.

Is there a way for MySql or ZF2 to return something like:

```
'table1.id', 'table1.name', 'table2.id', table2.name'
```

So I can then filter from there without having to do an as in the query:

```
SELECT 'table1.id as table1_id', 'table1.name as tablel1_name', 'table2.id as table2_id', table2.name as table2_name'
```

Thanks!

Comment: MySql can do this. Remove `'` characters around your fields.